# Array data not rendering in data table using this.props - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, chart.js, papaparse

I have two react components. In which one of the components processes the CSV data using Papa Parse and another one renders the data table. I am using the first component to parse and send the data to the second component using this.props.

Here, I'm using the Jquery data table to render the CSV data in the web. Problem is I'm unable to render the data inside the data table using this.props. 
(this issue has been resolved by @drew-reese)

Also is it possible to render graph as defaultContent API option in data table? Please refer to `second component`.

Here Is What I'm trying,

`First component:`

```
var output = [];
class Tables extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          data: []
        }
      this.updateData = this.updateData.bind(this);
    }
    componentWillMount() {

      var csvFilePath = require("../data/input.csv");
      Papa.parse(csvFilePath, {
        header: true,
        download: true,
        skipEmptyLines: true,
        complete: this.updateData
      });
    }
    updateData(result) {
      output = result.data;
      output = output.map(obj => Object.values(obj));
      console.log(output) //this works
    this.setState({data: output})    
    }
    render() { 
        return(
            <div>
                <Charts data={this.state.data}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
  }
  export default Tables;
```

`Second comp`

```
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
const $ = require('jquery')
$.DataTable = require('datatables.net');
class Charts extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.el);
        this.$el = $(this.el)
        this.$el.DataTable({
            data: this.props.data,
            columns: [
                { title: "heading" },
                { title: "heading" },
                { title: "heading " },
                { title: "heading " },
                { title: " heading",\
                  defaultContent: <Line /> #chartjs graph
                 },
            ]
        })
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table className="display" width="100%" ref = {el => this.el = el }></table>
                <p>{this.props.data}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

//ChartJS line graph
<Line
    data={data}
    options={options} />
```

I have tried to display the same data inside a p tag, but not working. Actually i'm unable to pass the data from one component to another. Any ideas? Do I have to use any async or something. Or is there any better way to parse csv and display in a data table?

Is it possible to render a chart inside one of the columns in the data table? Please refer to the last column and defaultContent API section.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does changing hook changed anything `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount` ?

Comment: I changed `componentWillMount` to `componentDidMount`. Still the data table is empty.

Comment: Are you saying `this.props.data` isn't rendering within the `<p>` element? Or it is and the table isn't rendering the jquery data as expected?

Comment: this.props.data is the data for the data table. I checked by putting the data inside the data table and p tag. Both are actually not working.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? If you console.log the data in the `render` or `componentDidUpdate` functions does it see the data update when the parent sets new state?

Comment: Now the data is rendering inside the data table. I used `componentDidUpdate` method.

Comment: Awesome, that was what I suspected needed to be added. Unhid my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is because jquery operates outside of react and your child component only sets the table when it mounts. When the parent sets state with `data` the child sees the prop update and rerenders `<p>{this.props.data}</p>`, but the `<table />` does not get its data updated. If you refactor the jquery logic into utility functions and call the set data table in `componentDidMount` **and** update table in `componentDidUpdate` props update, you can take advantage of the component lifecycle functions to get the `<table />` data updated.

Using this [Link](https://medium.com/@zbzzn/integrating-react-and-datatables-not-as-hard-as-advertised-f3364f395dfa) this is *an* example of how your DataTable could be updated.

```
setDataTable = () => {
  this.$el = $(this.el);
  this.$el.DataTable({
    data: this.props.data,
    columns: [
      { title: "heading" },
      { title: "heading" },
      { title: "heading " },
      { title: "heading " },
      { title: " heading" },
    ]
  });
}

updateDataTable = () => {
  const table = $(this.el).DataTable();

  // logic to update table with updated data
  table.clear();
  table.rows.add(this.props.data);
  table.draw();
};

componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.el);
  this.setDataTable();
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  console.log(this.el);
  if (prevProps.data !== this.props.data) {
    this.updateDataTable();
  }
}
```

**Question** Why not use a more react way of rendering your data? Something like [MUI-Datatables](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables)?

Comment: There is no data inside the data table when using this method. I was getting an error of `setDataTable` not defined. So I tried setting `this.setDataTable = this.setDataTable.bind(this)` in the constructor. But still no data inside the data table. Also data table creates an error message namely `can't reinitialise the table`. Earlier I was able to render the table using `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: @Musthafa Ah, it's an instance function, so would be accessed as `this.setDataTable()`, updated. It's also an arrow function so you shouldn't need to bind `this` to it in the constructor. About initializing, or reinitializing, the DataTable, that I'm unsure of but can try some quick research about updating the data to improve my answer. I suspect when updating you don't need the columns.

Comment: Yeah, this is a great way of rendering data table inside react component. We can easily re-render the table with the latest data. As of now, there is no problem with re-initialization. I'll check with updating the data. I'm also trying to render a graph inside one of the columns. is it possible? I'm getting an error of [object Object]. Anyway thanks for the answer update.