# Jquery DataTable is not showing (ReactJs)

Tags: jquery, reactjs, datatables

I had referred to solutions such as [Array data not rendering in data table using this.props - ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60734861/array-data-not-rendering-in-data-table-using-this-props-reactjs?newreg=cdf26917c34d41869b41ff053bd99246)

and [TypeError: this.$el.DataTable is not a function( REACT.JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55468698/typeerror-this-el-datatable-is-not-a-function-react-js)

but I still have no idea why my table is not showing. And there will be error

> `this.$el.DataTable is not a function`

if I comment `if (!this.el) return;` in `componentDidMount`.

This is my code, `FetchData.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import DataTable from 'datatables.net';

$.DataTable = DataTable;

export class FetchData extends Component {
   static displayName = FetchData.name;

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        forecasts: [],
        loading: true
     };
   }

 componentDidMount() {
    this.populateWeatherData();
    if (!this.el) return;
    this.$el = $(this.el);
    this.$el.DataTable({
        data: this.props.forecasts,
        column: [
            { title: "Date" },
            { title: "Temp. (C)" },
            { title: "Temp. (F)" },
            { title: "Summary" }
        ]
    })
}

static renderForecastsTable(forecasts) {
    return (
        <div>
            <table id="dtBasicExample" data={forecasts} className="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" aria-labelledby="tabelLabel" cellSpacing="0" width="100%" ref={el => (this.el = el)}>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}

render() {
    let contents = this.state.loading
        ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
        : FetchData.renderForecastsTable(this.state.forecasts);
   
    return (
        <div>
        <h1 id="tabelLabel" >Weather forecast</h1>
        <p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>
        {contents}
        </div>
    );
}

async populateWeatherData() {
    const response = await fetch('weatherforecast');
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ forecasts: data, loading: false });
}
```

}

Comment: try moving your `async` `await` code here -->  `async componentDidMount() {
    await this.populateWeatherData();` and see if it works. i cannot test it right now in order to post an answer, so I'm writing it as a comment first.

Comment: Hi @Apostolos, i tried to move as what you suggested, and remain the async in populateWeatherData as well, but the table still not showing. i got this error if i remove async from populateWeatherData: `Syntax error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function `

Comment: is there a chance that you can put a codesandbox link in order to work on that and help you?